# The speed of circular motion

Tags: kinematics, vectors, calculus

This question comes from my previous question asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770935/)

$$\vec v_2 = \vec v_1 + \vec v_\perp.$$

I think the logic I'm making a mistake is I presume that $\vec v_\perp = adt$ in x-direction. This presumes that during $dt$ time interval, $a$ is constant, hence this gives us > 0 value which means $\vec v_2 > \vec v_1$.

After seeing another [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423370/), I realize $a$ is not constant during $dt$ but even if it's not and changing, then we could split $dt$ again in even smaller intervals($dt_1, dt_2, dt_3,...$) and say that $v_\perp = a_1dt_1 + a_2dt_2 + a_3dt_3+...$. This way, $a$ is not constant over $dt$. but now this should give us 0 and the only way this is possible is if over small $dt$ interval, $a$ increases, then decreases and overally results in 0. What's the non-intuitive, solid proof that this is what happens?

Another way proving this is $$ v_2 = v_1\sqrt{1 + (\frac{adt}{v_1})^2} = v_1(1+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{adt}{v_1})^2 - \frac{1}{8}(\frac{adt}{v_1})^4 + \frac{1}{16}(\frac{adt}{v_1})^6)$$
and if $dt -> 0$, this becomes $v_2 = v_1$, but I don't understand this - what we gain with $dt -> 0$ intuitively? even if we take the interval that approaches zero, it doesn't say anything about acceleration and making the interval 0 doesn't seem proof to me.

Comment: Do you accept the existence of a position vector like $R(\cos\omega t, \sin\omega t)$? Are you actually asking for a "closed" form expression for the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions of this type that you are asking is really something you just have to prove for yourself and work it out.

In particular, you need to *draw pictures of the argument* until you can convince yourself that the zero time limit is necessary.

You should be starting from
$$\vec r=R\begin{pmatrix}\cos\omega t\\\sin\omega t\end  {pmatrix}\tag1$$
and working your way to getting centripetal acceleration formula $\vec a=-\omega^2\vec r$

But your problem at hand is with the velocity vector. Draw the pizza slice for the $2\mathrm dt$ time slice centred around $t=0$, i.e.
$$\tag2\vec v(0)=u\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end  {pmatrix}\qquad\bigwedge\qquad\vec v(\pm\mathrm dt)=u\begin{pmatrix}\mp\sin(\omega\mathrm dt)\\\cos(\omega\mathrm dt)\end  {pmatrix}$$

1. Show that $2\vec{\mathrm dv}\equiv\vec v(+\mathrm dt)-\vec v(-\mathrm dt)=-2u\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\omega\mathrm dt)\\0\end  {pmatrix}$ and draw this on the pizza slice. You may choose the equivalent form using angles rather than times.
2. Using the definiton of acceleration as $\vec a=\frac{2\vec{\mathrm dv}}{2\mathrm dt}$ and the mathematical result that $\lim_{\varphi\to0}\frac{\sin\varphi}{\varphi}=1$, show that $\vec a=-\omega u\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end  {pmatrix}$
3. Now, explore what happens if you wish not to take the limit $\mathrm dt\to0$; how much should $|\vec a|$ shrink if you want to preserve the speed if you take $\mathrm dt$ to be finite? What direction should the vectors be in relation to each other?
4. Take a step back and start from position $\vec r$ and obtain the same results relating velocity of uniform circular motion and position.
5. Using the earlier relationship between velocity and acceleration, and now velocity and position, show that $\vec a=-\omega^2\vec r$
6. Repeat all the arguments with arbitrary time $t$ rather than $t=0$, all with taking $\mathrm dt\to0$

Comment: Working on this, thanks a lot. Any reason though why textbooks show that $ a = \frac{v^2}{r} $ without vector quantity ? if this is like it, then $a$ seems like constant and positive, so its speed should be changing.

Comment: Because centripetal acceleration concept predated vectors. They did not have the language to express the more precise and accurate thing we can now write down.

Comment: Err, that a formula just refers to the magnitude, not the direction of the acceleration. It’s just simpler to say centripetal than writing out unit vectors.

Comment: well, they also don't include minus sign for acceleration. They show $a = \frac{w^2}{r}$ without minus sign. Maybe because $r$ vector and $a$ vector have opposite direction ?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think I completely understand derivation of $\frac {w^2}{r}$ but problem is this derivation only holds true if you assume magnitude of velocities don't change and all the textbooks just follow triangle similarities rule(which I'm sure you're aware of). but that for sure doesn't prove that speed doesn't change.  in your way, having a hard time following what (2) means at all. Probably would be best if I could look at an image which depicts what is $2dt$, and other quantities. but you've already done your best

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think this is what you meant - https://ibb.co/TKCkwsg . if $u$ is just a vector representation, I wonder how you got $\vec v(dt) = -sinwdt$.

Comment: The picture is mostly correct, but that is the position v.s. velocity picture, which should be around the x axis. You should be having the velocity v.s. acceleration picture, that is around the y axis. You also forgot to draw the $\Delta r$ that is horizontal in this picture.

Comment: That is, in my Equation (2), the two slanted radial vectors are $\vec v$ at slightly before and after time zero, the vertical radial vector is $\vec v$ at time zero, which is the centre time that we should be considering as the representative, and $2\vec{\mathrm dv}$ is horizontal connecting the tips of the two slanted radial vectors. Then you can see the perpendicularity between the centre representative velocity and the overall acceleration.

Comment: Ignoring directions and just considering magnitude, $a=\frac{v^2}r=\omega^2 r\neq\frac{\omega^2}{r}$ and yes, acceleration and position have opposite directions and hence the minus sign in the vectorial form. The correct way to teach centripetal acceleration is to first consider uniform circular motion, i.e. you already assumed/know that speed does not change, and derive that the acceleration is perpendicular.

Comment: The logic is that parallel acceleration, you already know how it changes speed without change of direction, perpendicular acceleration, you now learn that it causes direction change without speed change, and vectors are a linear system allowing for superposition, and thus the full behaviour of having both kinds of acceleration can thus be decomposed and understood. You then verify this is correct by considering non-uniform circular motion in vertical plane, where gravity makes it go faster and slower. Everything works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147102/discussion-between-chemistry-and-naturallyinconsistent).

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is a vector quantity which has both magnitude and direction $$\vec{V}=V\vec{i}_v$$where $\vec{i}_v$ is a unit vector in the direction of motion (which can vary along the path of motion). The acceleration is equal to the vector time derivative of the velocity:$$\vec{a}=\frac{dV}{dt}\vec{i}_v+V\frac{d\vec{i}_v}{dt}$$In circular motion with constant speed, the magnitude of the velocity vector V is constant, and the acceleration vector reduces to $$\vec{a}=V\frac{d\vec{i}_v}{dt}$$The component of the acceleration vector in the direction tangent to the circular particle path is obtained by dotting the acceleration vector with the unit vector in the direction of motion:  $$a_v=\vec{i}_v\centerdot\vec{a}=V\vec{i}_v\centerdot\frac{d\vec{i}_v}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}V\frac{(\vec{i}_v\centerdot \vec{i}_v)}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}V\frac{d1}{dt}=0$$Thus, the tangential component of the acceleration is zero, which is, of course, consistent with the tangential velocity (speed) being constant.