# Problem with the constant magnitude of vectors if the change in the same vector is perpendicular to it

Tags: kinematics, vectors, differentiation, calculus

**Note**: I am merely a highschool student attempting to self-study Classical Mechanics, some of the assumptions I make are perhaps wrong, so please bear with me. Thank you.

---

This while can be condensed to circular motion, gives no answers through the related question [The speed of circular motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/771097/) because that talks about why the time limit is zero which I have already presumed, my question talks about a substantial increase in magnitude even if the limit is zero.

---

As described in *An Introduction to Mechanics by Kleppner and Kolenkow*, given a vector $\vec{A}$, if $\vec{dA}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{A}$, the change in $\lvert A\rvert$ is infinitely small and hence we say that only the direction of the vector changes while the magnitude remains constant if $\vec{dA}$ is *always* perpendicular to $\vec{A}$.

But given that the $\vec{dA}$ is *always* perpendicular to $\vec{A}$, we may say it acts perpendicular to $\vec{A}$ for all instants. So, for all instants:
$$\lvert A\rvert=\sqrt{A_0^2+dA^2}$$
If we consider $A_0$ to be the initial magnitude. But if we don't initially neglect $dA^2$, as we move on from one instant to the next, we get something like:
$$\lvert A\rvert=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{A_0^2+dA^2}+dA^2}+dA^2}...$$
As we state that it applies for all instants, and the number of instants in a general, observable time interval approaches infinity, $\lvert A\rvert$ becomes:
$$\sqrt{A_0^2+n\cdot{dA^2}}$$
where, ${n\to \infty}$ as it denotes the number of iterations we have gone through. Again since $dA$ is not exactly $0$, I believe that there should be at least some substantial increase in $\lvert A\rvert$ in a general time interval. This contradicts the earlier statement that:

> Only the direction of the vector changes while the magnitude remains constant if $\vec{dA}$ is *always* perpendicular to $\vec{A}$.

So, I wish to understand if my statements are correct or if not, where did I go wrong.
Also, curiously enough as ${dA^2\to 0}$ and ${n\to \infty}$, $\lim{n\cdot{A^2}}=\infty\cdot{0}$, which is an interesting, if perhaps wrong conclusion.

Comment: No. You are thinking of the Pythagorean theorem, which will indeed become a problem if the $\vec{\mathrm dA}$ has any finite magnitude. It is thus important that they are infinitesimial. There are plenty of resources here talking about this problem, and it is often the case that you will most clearly understand it if you derive the correct answer yourself.

Comment: In my opinion this is the kind of problems in physics where trying to hide the correct mathematical machinery in order to yield a supposedly easier physical solution only makes things much more difficult. My approach would be using derivatives and the geometric interpretation of linear algebra, but I understand that you may have not been exposed to this concepts yet. Unfortunately I do not like the intuitive way,

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I understand that since the magnitude of $/vec{dA}$ is infinitesimal, this shouldn't necessarily pose a problem, but intuitively, infinitesimal is still larger than 0, just larger but still, for some finite iterations, the vector should show change in magnitude

Comment: @MatteoMenghini You'd be correct on that, I am hoping to have learned linear algebra by myself soon enough though, but that is still a time too far away for me to leave this problem

Comment: Look at the answer of mine in the linked question. If you simply just do the mathematics properly, draw the things out, you will definitely get the correct answer and be convinced that the result we are trying to tell you, is correct as it is.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I apologise but even though I am trying to understand what you're getting at, it does not answer my question. It shows me how to derivate $a=-\omega^2\cdot{r}$ to prove that the zero time limit is necessary but again, it does not answer my question. The zero time limit is just that, a limit, dt is still a quantity, an inconceivably small one, but still finite and if it be added over and over again, no matter how small it is, after some number of times,  it should show up to be substantial, after all that is the basis for integral calculus. Or as far as I am aware atleast

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Also the mathematics or perhaps simply the notations are a little difficult to understand considering I am completely self taught

Comment: If you draw it out, you will see that the $\mathrm dt\to0$ needs to be strictly zero for that to become correct. The definition of infinitesimal is not a finite quantity.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, infinitesimal is not a finite quantity, but it is not zero either. And integral calculus would go completely haywire if ${dt\to 0}$ was to be $0$ itself since it employs the summation of these infinitesimals.

Comment: You should really be using $\Delta A$ as a variable here as you are mixing regular algebraic manipulations with an object that isn't really an algebraic variable. I can't really comment as I'm on mobile but it should be possible to show that the limit is in fact zero leaving the magnitude of A unchanged. Perhaps writing $\Delta A$ as a function of the old and new velocity with the acceleration explicitly written out. Since the change depends on the slices of time $t$ it should depend on the reciprocal of *n*.

Comment: @Triatticus I suppose I am mixing some things here but I could not represent it any better way than this, and it does not depend on the slices of time but rather the number of times we change the vector

Comment: Do you know limits, derivatives, hyperreal numbers, or dual numbers? If not, then the best answer is to just wait until you have the necessary background

Comment: @Dale No I don't, but that is really something I don't want to do

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are trying to treat $dA$ as though it were a real number. You simply cannot do that, it isn’t a real number.

If you want to use real numbers then $d$ is an operator on $A$ which is evaluated in a specified limit. That is beyond the scope of this answer.

Instead, you can treat $dA$ as an infinitesimal. Infinitesimals are “infinitely small”, and they are not real numbers, just like infinity is not a real number.

Recall when developing imaginary numbers we said $i=\sqrt{-1}$ or equivalently $i^2=-1$. Now, there is no real number that satisfies those equations. So we just assigned $i$ to be a prototype non-real number that had those properties. We then constructed all of the complex numbers using the prototype imaginary number.

Similarly, we can develop what are called dual numbers. Just as we did with $i$ we start with a prototype number $\epsilon$ that has the following properties: $0<\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^2=0$. No real number satisfies those conditions, so the dual numbers are a new class of numbers. We can then construct all of the dual numbers using this prototype infinitesimal number.

Then $dA$ is an infinitesimal change in $A$ which is $dA=k\epsilon$ for some real $k$. Then $dA^2=k^2\epsilon^2=k^2 0=0$. So you cannot choose or not choose to neglect $dA^2$. It is zero.

There are other infinitesimal number systems, like the hyperreals, that I prefer over the dual numbers. But dual numbers are the easiest to explain. The point is simply that you cannot treat an infinitesimal like a real number. Whatever class of numbers you choose, you have to treat infinitesimals by the correct rules.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, which I probably am, but I looked at $dA^2$ and thought of if we do a double derivative of some function, $y=f(A)$ over A, It leads to $\frac{d^2y}{dA^2}$ and if that is equal to say some constant function, $n$ then is $dA^2$, not something? Particularly is it not $\frac{d^2y}{n}$? And If as I did, we do not instantly remove the $dA^2$ and keep repeating the change for one instant to the next, after some no. of iterations don't we arrive at $n\cdot{dA^2}$ which by my previous example of taking the double derivative of some function should by the way, be defined.

Comment: Also thank you for answering, you have come the closest to clearing my doubt

Comment: @AdyanshMishra in that context you have to recognize that $d^2/dA^2$ is not a division by the number $dA^2$, which would be division by zero and is undefined even in the dual numbers. Instead it is just an idiomatic way of writing an operator: differentiation with respect to a variable $A$. Again, when you are using infinitesimals and derivatives and such things, you cannot just throw things around, you have to follow the rules and notation for the specific mathematical objects you are working with.

Comment: I know it is the derivative of one variable over another but if you really overlook the semantics considering infinitesimals, the derivative of one variable over other is just the division of one very small quantity by another very small quantity as the change in both quantities approaches zero, but never quite becomes it, this can be given by an example of derivating a constant function, say $y=3$ over $x$, since $y$ never changes, the change in $y$ is 0 and the division of change in y over change is x is again, as expected 0.

Comment: @AdyanshMishra you cannot “overlook the semantics” of a given number system. That is the whole issue. You have to follow the rules of whatever number system you use

Comment: It's fine, leave it, thanks for your input, I am not overlooking the rules of the number system by the way, if $dA^2$ was to be exactly zero, there'd be nothing like the integral existing

Comment: Yes, you are. The issue is what type of quantity a given expression is. In the real numbers $dA$ is not a real number. It is an operator $d$ applied to $A$. In the dual numbers $dA$ can be an infinitesimal number, but even in the dual numbers $d^2/dA^2$ is an operator and not a number. In any number system you have to understand what type of mathematical object a given expression is. Within each number system you must use it according to the type of quantity it is in that system. In the dual numbers the number $dA^2$ is indeed exactly zero, while the operator $d^2/dA^2$ is not division by zero

Comment: It has been some time sinc, but since $(dA)^2$ is a differential, shouldn't it not be $0$, as shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942006/why-is-it-considered-that-mathrm-d-x2-0there)? I also asked the same question in the [mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747787/on-the-rotation-of-vectors), they closed down the one here, and while it seems right in some cases, the answer seems inconsistent. For instance, it is right if you assume $v\cdot{v}=C$. a constant you get $v\cdot{v'}=0$. Which is right contrary to my approach.

Comment: Also it has been a rather long time but I'll hope for your response. I do understand I am wrong though, just not where as I, in my question present it.

Comment: @AdyanshMishra comments are not intended for discussion and follow-up. For discussion I recommend physicsforums.com. I am sorry that my answer didn’t help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a vector  with his magnitude$~|A|~$ and a norm direction vector $~\hat g~$

$$\vec A=|A|\,\hat g=|A|\,\begin{bmatrix}
             \cos(\phi) \\
             \sin(\phi) \\
           \end{bmatrix}$$

with

$$\vec {dA}=|A|\,d\hat g=|A|\,\begin{bmatrix}
             -\sin(\phi) \\
             \cos(\phi) \\
           \end{bmatrix}$$

thus  $~\vec {dA}\cdot \vec A=0$

> Only the direction of the vector changes while the magnitude remains constant if $\vec{dA}$ is *always* perpendicular to $\vec{A}$.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the problem I presented?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the thing wich we call infinitesimal.If one really takes a $\Delta A ≠0 $ you are right, A changes in direction and magnitude. But than in mathematics (and physics) one thinks of $\Delta A $ getting smaller and smaller we say we take "the limit" for $\Delta A$ to zero and only then we call it dA. And you can see the result if you look at a circular motion with constant magnitude of v, you only have a force and so an acceleration in direction of the center, so you can have circular motion on a mass going around on a string.You will learn it as soon as you learn about so called real analysis, but without it you have just to believe it for the moment.

Comment: Ah well, I suppose I will have to wait then, but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Also, since its only the limit, dA is still larger than 0 and adding a number greater than 0 again and again should at some time wield a finite number

Comment: the limit is not larger than zero, it only say you can not measure it once it gets too close to zero. one example ist 1/n if n gets larger and larger, of cause if you put in n=10000000000000 you get close to 0 but it is not zero. So what mathematic claims if n goes to infinity 1/n goes to zero, since you can not name any number, where I can not find a smaller one except I name zero.

Comment: but n can never go to infinity, can it now?

Comment: if you tell me the last  or biggest natural number a would agree that it does not go to infinity. We say n goes to infinity, if to every number n you can tell I know a larger one