Why the normal vector addition does not seem to work in centripetal acceleration?
It is known that centripetal acceleration acts at an angle of 90 degrees to the tangential velocity. This acceleration vector then causes an increment $\mathbf{a} \Delta t$ to be added to the original tangential velocity. This vector addition triangle is a right-angled triangle.
The question then follows: Since the vector addition triangle is a right-angle triangle, and we know in a right-angled triangle the resultant velocity's direction and magnitude will change. So then why does the speed remain constant in centripetal acceleration?

Once again it is necessary to consider the fact that we are dealing with infinitesimally small quantities. In the limit there is no difference between a right angled triangle and a narrow isosceles triangle. I wonder if it would be helpful to think of the derivation is a slightly different way, considering the velocity vector one moment before, and one moment after, the desired acceleration. In this way one avoids ever drawing a right-angled triangle.

It is the same with constant speed  in circular motion, and velocity in right angle to radius, but still radius stays constant. If the centripetal acceleration is nit v^2/r but greater or less v and r change.

This question is similar to: Rate of change of vectors in circular motion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See my answer on the linked question. If the change is perpendicular, then there is no first-order change the magnitude in $\Delta t$. So there can be no change after integration.

Its important to note that the velocity is infact not constant,as it is changing its direction.
But,I'm going to show you why the speed is constant if we have the fact that the angle between the force vector and the velocity vector is 90° everytime.
The angle between the vectors being 90° is just  saying;
$$ \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{v} = 0$$
$$\implies \vec{F} \cdot \frac{d\vec{s}}{dt} = 0$$
$$\implies \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = 0$$
$$\implies W = 0$$
$$\implies \Delta KE = 0$$
$$\implies |\vec{v}| = \text{constant}$$
So, if the angle between the velocity and force vector is 90° throughout, the object in its new path of motion will have a constant speed.

The concern raised in this question, as I understand it, is that we start with a tangential velocity:

But then, the acceleration, being perpendicular to the velocity, causes the increment $\mathbf{a} \Delta t$ (the blue vector in the diagram) of velocity to be added, thus forming a right angled triangle of vector addition:

This being the case, the concern raised is due to Pythagoras' theorem; the new velocity vector seems to be longer.
Proper formal proofs (or the argument via work in another answer) can sidestep these problems but in this answer I am attempting to allay the concerns raised about this pictorial/visual argument. Perhaps the best way to do this is to visualise the following situation:

We see in the diagram above that for the moment under consideration, the starting velocity is $\mathbf{v}_A$ and the ending velocity is $\mathbf{v}_B$. Now consider the average acceleration during this short interval. Well, being the average it seems intuitively reasonable to imagine this acceleration being concentrated at the point exactly between point A and point B. Now we have an isosceles triangle instead of a right angled triangle and so the velocity vector does not change its magnitude.
Final comment: Of course, when limits are taken it doesn't matter whether we consider the right triangle or this isosceles triangle. Nevertheless, from an intuitive point of view, hopefully the original poster may find this second visual argument a little more convincing.

For the kind of student that is confused about this, I think an answer along this line of reasoning is the only thing that will dispel their confusion. But you might want to include the mathematics, which I have here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/771100

Yes! - I attempted with this answer to specifically address the concerns raised by the visual argument. It goes without question that a proper full mathematical approach alleviates any problems. Nevertheless, I think there is still value and satisfaction in refining a visual argument to the point where it is convincing - even when one is already familiar with a rigorous mathematical definition.

I was trying to say that both visual and mathematical are needed; and that they cannot be two separate discussions. They have to be one coherent combination of both visual and mathematical, talking about the same thing, and then the generic mathematical theorems and their proofs.

Speed but not velocity is constant. The velocity vector changes all the time exactly due to the acceleration component.

You cannot add acceleration and velocity by vector addition because they are quantities of different dimension.  You cannot add m/s and m/s$^2$.
What you can add is velocity and the product of acceleration and an infinitesimal time interval:
$$\vec v + \vec a~dt$$
And if you perform this addition for uniform circular motion you will have adjusted the direction of the velocity vector by an amount $d \vec \theta $,  which is the amount it would change over a short time $dt$ to follow the circular path.

There was never any intention to suggest that an acceleration vector was to be added to a velocity vector - the fact that the increment to be added was aDt was implied in the answer.

But I have made a small edit in my answer so that it is less prone to being misunderstood.

I was trying to correct an apparent misconception in the original question for the OP, which has been edited out

If the curve is given in parametric polar coordinates (r(t),θ(t))
, the velocity and acceleration vectors can be calculated in the moving base . (We denote by a point the derivation with respect to the parameter t) :
$\vec{r}=r\vec{u}$
$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}\vec{u}+r\frac{d\vec{u}}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}\vec{u}+r\frac{d\vec{u}}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$
$ \vec {V}=\dot {r}\vec {u}+r\dot {\theta }\vec {v}$
in the same way we find that the acceleration
$ \vec {A}=\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}=(\ddot {r}-r\dot {\theta }^{2})\vec {u}+(r\ddot {\theta }+2\dot {r}\dot {\theta })\vec {v}$
if: $\;\;r=cst\;,\;\dot{\theta}=cst\;\;$==> $\vec {V}=r\dot {\theta }\vec {v}$
$\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}=-r\dot {\theta }^{2}\vec {u}\;\;$i.e.
$\;\;d\vec{V}=\vec{A}\,dt\,=-r\dot {\theta }^{2}dt\,\vec {u}=-\frac{ {V }^{2}}{r}dt\,\vec {u}$
the variation of the $\vec{V}$ is on the axis with direction vector   $\vec{u}\perp \vec{V}$ .
